# Javascript jquery parallax scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the parallax scrolling of the website.
Now it only works when the mouse cursor is in the red box. 
I have been trying to fix it all day so I came here for help.

```
    //$('html, body, #containerBox, #BackGround').mousewheel(function (e, delta)
$('html, body, *').mousewheel(function (e, delta)
{
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 10);
    e.preventDefault();
});

//Parallax scrolling

window.onscroll = displayDate;
window.onload = displayDate;

var scrollPosition = document.getElementById('panel1').scrollLeft;

if (scrollPosition > 80)
{
    document.getElementById("panel1Image").style.position = "relative";
    document.getElementById("panel1Image").style.top = (scrollPosition*1)+"px";
    document.getElementById("panel1Image").style.left = (scrollPosition*1)+"px";
}
```

Please help! Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/RpNyq/

Comment: The reason SO tells you to include code with a fiddle link is so you include code in your question, not so you put the fiddle link in a code block.

Comment: @smerny But the codes are in the fiddle link :O

Comment: Yes but people don't always want to go straight there - also it's good if you can narrow down the more relevant code to post in the question. Thanks for adding code.

Comment: @smerny This is the code that's not working. I have removed other code to focus on this part of my webpage.